# NTLM authentication not working with VCS 3 and higher version causing our ui application Woking improperly

Tags: java, spring, ntlm, ntlm-authentication, ntlmv2

My application on struts/spring which as a framework stopped working with vcs 3.x version as ntlm authentication not supporting it . Any suggestions?